# How do automaticly delete rows from other tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, delete

I have a MySql DB.

I have a table - recipes.
Also have 2 tables -ingredients and instructions. both have for each entry - a foreign key to the related recipe.

I want that when I delete an entry from the recipes table - to automaticly delete the related ingredients entries and instruction entries.

How?

Comment: From your comment it seems that I have to add the ON DELETE CASCADE to the table. Will that deleted the related entries? How can I alter the table to support it?

Comment: Defining the foreign keys with ON DELETE CASCADE may help you.

Comment: You have Alter the table structure have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Please put it as an answer so can mark it and you get the rate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are trying to do can easily be done by

**USING ON DELETE CASCADE AND ON UPDATE CASCADE(IF Required)**

While creating the foreign keys on your table.

For your reference have a look at [FOREIGN KEY Constraints.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: the table structure should by innodb. MyIsam does not work with this statment

Comment: Yes ofcourse!! As @Yoav is creating the FKeys in His tables so the engine will be InnDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query like this

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id 
INNER JOIN t3 on t1.id = t3.t1_id
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```